# iterate through a list of items inside lambda expression

Tags: c#, loops, lambda

I'm trying to loop through a list in a lambda expression.

Here is my code I though i could do.

```
var table = shipment.ShipmentItems.ToList();

for (int i = 0; i <= table.Count; i++)
        {
            shippedItems = shipment.Order.OrderItems.Where(x => x.Id != table[0].OrderItemId); ;
        }
```

I need to use each index in table, `table[1].OrderItemId`, `table[0].OrderItemId` etc

Whats the best way to do this.

Cheers

Comment: Did you mean: shippedItems = shipment.Order.OrderItems.Where(x => x.Id != table[i].OrderItemId)? Your question leaves us in the dark about the schema of your data. You are not likely to get great answers without describing the schema of shipment.

Answer (score -1):

is the end result all of the order items that are not in the shipment items list?

```
var orderItemIds = shipment.ShipmentItems.Select(si => si.OrderItemId).ToList();
var shippedItems = shipment.Order.OrderItems.Where(oi => !orderItemIds.Contains(oi.Id));
```